# Symfony @ParamConverter only for active row

Tags: php, symfony

```
product_show:
    path: /product/{id}
    controller: App\Controller\ProductController::show
    methods: GET
    requirements:
      id: \d+
```

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default": true})
     */
    private bool $active = true;

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function active(): bool
    {
        return $this->active;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    public function show(Product $product): Response
    {
        return $this->render('product/show.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When $product->active() return false, I want to send 404 response.

But it should be done without adding an if in controller action.

Perhaps I should modify something in ParamConverter. How can I do this? How can I overwrite ParamConverter behavior?

Comment: the paramconverter allows you to provide the repository function that ought to be used. If you add a repository function that only returns active product(s) for a product id, that should work fine. however, I don't see you actively using a paramconverter...

Answer (score 0):

You can [fetch via an Expression](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression) and use a custom function in your repository.

For example:

```
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
   /**
    * @Route("/product/{product_id}")
    * @Entity("product", expr="repository.findOneActive(product_id)")
    */
    public function show(Product $product): Response
    {
        return $this->render('product/show.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And in your ProductRepository:

```
class ProductRepository
{
    public function findOneActive($productId)
    {
        // your query here...
    }
}
```